# How to suppress or fix "possible misuse of unsafe.Pointer" warning by go vet?

Tags: go

Is there a way to suppress the `possible misuse of unsafe.Pointer` for a *specific line* (via a comment for example?). Or even better fix the code in my specific example?

I have a `windows.TRUSTEE` struct whose content are filled by a Windows API call. I want to access the `*windows.SID` that's in the `TrusteeValue` field. I know that the `TrusteeValue` field contains a `*windows.SID` because I perform this check: `entry.Trustee.TrusteeForm == windows.TRUSTEE_IS_SID && entry.Trustee.MultipleTrusteeOperation == windows.NO_MULTIPLE_TRUSTEE`. I also check if the Windows API call returned an error.

Here is a code snippet with the relevant part

```golang
if entry.Trustee.TrusteeForm == windows.TRUSTEE_IS_SID && entry.Trustee.MultipleTrusteeOperation == windows.NO_MULTIPLE_TRUSTEE {
    sid := (*windows.SID)(unsafe.Pointer(entry.Trustee.TrusteeValue)) // <--- this line results in "possible misuse of unsafe.Pointer" warning by go vet in go 1.20.4
    fmt.Println(sid.String())
}
```

So apparently the warning is a false positive. I want to suppress the warning for this line and still get the warning in other places where I might inadvertently misuse `unsafe.Pointer`.

There were some suggestions (on web and by Copilot) that I add comments like `//nolint:govet`, `//lint:ignore`, `//lint:ignore SA1015` or `nolint`

Thanks a lot in advance for help.

I wrote a short and complete golang program to reproduce my issue with code that's not relevant to the issue removed. Note that since this access Windows API the program will run only on Windows. The program loops the access control entries on "C:\Windows" folder and prints the SID

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "unsafe"

    "golang.org/x/sys/windows"
)

var (
    modadvapi32                    = windows.NewLazySystemDLL("advapi32.dll")
    procGetExplicitEntriesFromAclW = modadvapi32.NewProc("GetExplicitEntriesFromAclW")
)

func main() {
    filename := "C:\\Windows"

    sd, err := windows.GetNamedSecurityInfo(filename, windows.SE_FILE_OBJECT, windows.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to get security descriptor: %v", err)
    }

    dacl, _, err := sd.DACL()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("failed to get DACL: %v", err)
    }

    var entriesCount uint32
    var entries *windows.EXPLICIT_ACCESS

    ret, _, err := procGetExplicitEntriesFromAclW.Call(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(dacl)), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&entriesCount)), uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(&entries)))
    if ret != 0 {
        log.Fatalf("failed to get explicit entries from ACL: %v", err)
    }
    defer windows.LocalFree(windows.Handle(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(entries))))

    accessControlEntries := unsafe.Slice(entries, entriesCount)
    for _, entry := range accessControlEntries {
        if entry.Trustee.TrusteeForm == windows.TRUSTEE_IS_SID && entry.Trustee.MultipleTrusteeOperation == windows.NO_MULTIPLE_TRUSTEE {
            sid := (*windows.SID)(unsafe.Pointer(entry.Trustee.TrusteeValue)) // <--- this line results in "possible misuse of unsafe.Pointer" warning by go vet in go 1.20.4
            fmt.Println(sid.String())
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: `//nolint:govet` is recognized by the golaingci-lint tool, but not by go vet itself. See [this issue](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/17058) for discussion why disabling false positives was declined in go vet itself.

Comment: I agree that the conversion looks ok (though don't you want `unsafe.Slice(&entries,`?). You could relegate the minimal amount of surrounding code to a separate file which you don't deal with often, or maybe use `go vet -unsafeptr=false` when dealing with this package.

Comment: @JonathanHall Thanks for the reply. I read the issue you linked and TBH I don't agree with them. No matter how smart the tool becomes there will always be false positives (specially with stuff like unsafe). Having the tools report always report the false positives will train my brain to ignore them whenever I see them, and will make me miss real issues. 

I decided to silence go vet in vscode, and using golangci-lint tool instead. but it seems golangci-lint doesn't report unsafeptr analyzer errors.  I opened an [issue](https://github.com/golangci/golangci-lint/issues/3820) on their repo.

Comment: @JimB Thanks for the reply. Actually `unsafe.Slice` works fine in this code. My project has many parts that use unsafe.Pointer as it deals with ACLs, Registry, Eventlog, SIDs, Windows API callbacks that pass pointers, etc. Separating the false positives from the other code would be a hassle and would mess my project's structure.

The unsafeptr warning is actually very helpful, and it did help me avoid some bugs. I would like to have go vet report them, then I can manually vet them and write unit tests for each case, then suppress them one by one if they are actually safe.

Comment: can you try: `//nolint:gosec`. 
With this comment, you are telling go vet to ignore warnings related to security (gosec) on this specific line

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VSCode, you can create settings to ignore this false-positive.

path:

> .vscode/settings.json

```
{
   "go.useLanguageServer": true, // if this is true, needs gopls/analyses flag.
    "go.vetFlags": [
        "-unsafeptr=false"
    ],
    "gopls": {
        "analyses": { "unsafeptr": false }
    }
}
```